# Charge distribution and electric field on a conductive sheet

Tags: electricity, charge, density, dirac-delta-distributions

I have a sheet of paper, clad with a half-circle shape of conductive material. The half circle is not filled to the center. The inner radius is about 8cm, and the outer radius about 12cm, not that the measurements are very important here, but you get the idea. The area between the radii is filled out with the conductive material.
Both ends of the conductive track are hooked up to a voltage source spanning the width of the track. The pole potentials are 2V and 0V and potential can be measured anywhere on the track. Measurements show that there is no difference in potential between points situated on the same radial line.
I need to know a)the electric field and b)the charge distribution on the track. I believe the electric field should be at all points perpendicular and inversely proportional to the radius (correct me if I'm wrong), but when it comes to the charge distribution I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

In a driven conductor, the field should be proportional to, and in the direction of, the gradient of the charge density.  In this case you may have positive charge near the positive terminal and negative charge at the other end.  On a curve of larger radius, the charge density should be smaller, but the rate of change with radius must angle the field to follow the curve.